# Linq join without equals

Tags: c#, linq, join

I have a list of rectangles and a list of points. I want to construct a LINQ query that will match the list of points with their corresponding rectangles. Something like this:

```
// Does not compile
var matches = from rect in rectangles
              join point in points on rect.Contains(point)
              select new { rect, point };
```

How does one accomplish something like this with LINQ?

EDIT:

My lists are equal size - I have one point to match with one rectangle, and the rectangles don't overlap.

However, the point of the question isn't so much to solve this one specific problem. I'm interested, in general, how to join two lists on any condition other than simply 'equals'.

Comment: Learn to love LINQ method-chains and these sorts of questions vanish in a flash.

Comment: I actually prefer LINQ method chains - if you can find a way to solve this problem in that manner, I'd love an answer!

Comment: What does it mean to you for a rectangle to contain a point? The System.Drawing.Rectangle has a Location Point. Do you mean does the point match a rectangle's location point or is it somewhere inside the area of a given rectangle?

Comment: @ConradFrix It's my own implementation of a rectangle... this is just an example - what happens inside Contains() doesn't matter; I'm just looking for a way to do a join without simple 'equals' on two properties.

Comment: @Phil, hmm, I spoke too soon.  Totally forgot `Join` was purely key-based.

Comment: @Phil - can you describe what you want to achieve - without using the work join preferrably, because I think there is a misunderstanding somewhere. Do you have a list of points (i.e. you want to find one rectangle) or a list of lists of points (and you want to find a matching rectangle for each list)? Will it be a match only if all the points are matching or if any of them matches the current rectangle?

Comment: @Joanna I two equally sized lists - one point for one rectangle.

Comment: Do you want one rectangle per point? Can the rectangles overlap?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use multiple from clauses to achieve a join

```
 var matches = from p in points
               from r in rectangles
               where r.Contains(p)
               select new { r, p };
```

Multiple from clauses are more flexible than the join syntax ([see myth 5 of 10 LINQ myths](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/10linqmyths.aspx)). You need to learn only this one and all joins will be easy.

Comment: Note that, with non-overlapping rectangles, this will actually perform quite a bit of extra work, as it will check every rectangle against every point, and not short circuit out as soon as a matching rectangle is found for a point.  If each point can existing in >1 rectangle, this is really good, but if the rects are non-overlapping, it's going to be overkill.

Comment: +1 but as mentioned by @Reed Copsey, this kind of query might not perform well for large data sets.

Comment: Yes a cross product can become very expensive especially if you join several lists you get exponential (2 lists quadratic, 3 cubic, 4 bicubic, ...) running times.

Comment: Can you make this a left join instead of inner join?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Enumerable.ToLookup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549073.aspx) to create a lookup table per rectangle:

```
var lookup = points.ToLookup(p => rectangles.First(r => r.Contains(point)));
```

Using this is similar to a grouping query:

```
foreach(var group in lookup)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Rectangle {0} contains:", group.Key);
    foreach(var point in group)
        Console.WriteLine("    {0}", point);
}
```

On a side note - this query is quadratic in nature, and likely to perform poorly with very large datasets.  If you need to do this for many points and/or many rectangles, you may wish to investigate spatial data structures for quicker lookups.  That may not be an issue in this case, however.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried just using a where statement, instead of joining them:

```
var matches = from rectangle in rectangles
              from point in points
              where rectangle.Contains(point)
              select new { rectangle, point };
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of getting what you want.

```
points.Select(p => new { Point = p, Rectangles = rectangles.Where(r => r.Contains(p) });
```

This caters to the case where a point may be in many rectangles.

```
points.Select(p => new { Point = p, Rectangle = rectangles.First(r => r.Contains(p) });
```

This caters to the case where a point is in exactly one rectangle.

The second case should work best in your scenario.